# Why is where clause omitted in jpa Criteria Query with JOINS?

Tags: jpa-2.0

I clearly defined a WHERE statements in the main and sub-query. This is printed in the JPA log if I omit the subquery. However, the same where clause ist not applied, if I add the subquery. What is it about JPA Criteria query, that omits the WHERE clause (selection σ)?

```
    // 1) MainQuery
    // Create the FROM
    Root<PubThread> rootPubThread = cq.from(PubThread.class);
    // Create the JOIN fro the first select: join-chaining. You only need the return for ordering. e.g. cq.orderBy(cb.asc(categoryJoin.get(Pub_.title)));
    Join<Pub, PubCategory> categoryJoin = rootPubThread.join(PubThread_.pups).join(Pub_.pubCategory);
    // Create the WHERE
    cq.where(criteriaBuilder.not(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThread.get(PubThread_.id), threadId)));
    // Create the SELECT, at last
    cq.select(rootPubThread).distinct(true);

    // 2) Subquery
    Subquery<PubThread> subquery = cq.subquery(PubThread.class); 
    Root<PubThread> rootPubThreadSub = subquery.from(PubThread.class); 
    subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThread.get(PubThread_.id), threadId));
    Join<Pub, PubCategory> categoryJoinSub = rootPubThreadSub.join(PubThread_.pups).join(Pub_.pubCategory);
    subquery.select(rootPubThreadSub);

    Predicate correlatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThreadSub.get(PubThread_.id), rootPubThread);
    subquery.where(correlatePredicate);
    cq.where(criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery));
```

Here is the output of this query:

```
select distinct
    pubthread0_.id as id3_,
    pubthread0_.dateCreated as dateCrea2_3_,
    pubthread0_.dateModified as dateModi3_3_,
    pubthread0_.name as name3_
from
    pubthread pubthread0_
        inner join
    pub_pubthread pups1_ ON pubthread0_.id = pups1_.pubThreads_id
        inner join
    pub pub2_ ON pups1_.pups_id = pub2_.id
        inner join
    PubCategory pubcategor3_ ON pub2_.pubCategoryId = pubcategor3_.id
where 
    exists( select 
            pubthread4_.id
        from
            pubthread pubthread4_
                inner join
            pub_pubthread pups5_ ON pubthread4_.id = pups5_.pubThreads_id
                inner join
            pub pub6_ ON pups5_.pups_id = pub6_.id
                inner join
            PubCategory pubcategor7_ ON pub6_.pubCategoryId = pubcategor7_.id
        where
             pubthread4_.id=pubthread0_.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. As soon as you defined a predicate, the where clause is rejected. That is for sure. Combine the where clause with a conjunction within a `Predicate` instance and append it in the where clause. Use an `criteriaBuilder.and(..., ...)`. To semantically do the same thing.

So now, there are two conjunctional predicates: One for the subquery and one for the main query. Notice the obsolete single `select(...)` I ruled out from the code (it's commented).

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<PubThread> mainQuery = criteriaBuilder
            .createQuery(PubThread.class);

    // 1) MainQuery
    // Create the FROM
    Root<PubThread> rootPubThread = mainQuery.from(PubThread.class);
    // Create the JOIN from the first select: join-chaining. You only need the return for ordering. e.g. cq.orderBy(cb.asc(categoryJoin.get(Pub_.title)));
    Join<Pub, PubCategory> categoryJoin = rootPubThread.join(PubThread_.pups).join(Pub_.pubCategory);
    // Create the WHERE
    mainQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.not(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThread.get(PubThread_.id), threadId)));
    // Create the SELECT, at last
    mainQuery.select(rootPubThread).distinct(true);

    // 2) Subquery
    Subquery<PubThread> subquery = mainQuery.subquery(PubThread.class); 
    Root<PubThread> rootPubThreadSub = subquery.from(PubThread.class); 
    //subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThread.get(PubThread_.id), threadId));
    Join<Pub, PubCategory> categoryJoinSub = rootPubThreadSub.join(PubThread_.pups).join(Pub_.pubCategory);
    subquery.select(rootPubThreadSub);

    //Predicate correlatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThreadSub.get(PubThread_.id), rootPubThread);
    Predicate correlatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.and(
            criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThreadSub.get(PubThread_.id), rootPubThread),
            criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThread.get(PubThread_.id), threadId)
            );
    subquery.where(correlatePredicate);     

    //Predicate correlatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThreadSub.get(PubThread_.id), rootPubThread);
    Predicate mainPredicate = criteriaBuilder.and(
            criteriaBuilder.not(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThread.get(PubThread_.id), threadId)),
            criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery)
            );
    //cq.where(criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery));
    mainQuery.where(mainPredicate);


    TypedQuery<PubThread> typedQuery = em.createQuery(mainQuery);
    List<PubThread> otherPubThreads = typedQuery.getResultList();

    return otherPubThreads;
```

The result is something like this

```
    where
    pubthread4_.id=pubthread0_.id 
    and pubthread0_.id=1
```